# Arranging numbers

Tags: combinatorics

First things first, this is my first post and I might not add the right tags and the title might not help me very much, please feel free to add tags or change the title if mod thinks this is too confusing or generic !

Alright, the thing is this, I have a number of n lenght and I'm having a hard time to correctly arrange/permutate the numbers, for example

2102

I'm trying to figure out how many combinations can be done with those numbers. My problem is around the fact that changing the 5th and the 1th number in said example gives me the same number, more than that the fact that I can't put the 0 as the thousand digit,
I must gather that the 0's and the repetition of algarisms in the number play the tricky part of this, but I'm pretty struck on this. 
Could any one explain how I get to the right formula? I would expect to get a 9 out of the above example, unless I've forgotten some possible combination

Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of distinct ways of permuting a list is given by the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).  If we have $d$ digits and $n_i$ copies of digit $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,9\}$, then the number of permutations is $$\binom{d}{n_0, n_1, \ldots, n_9}=\frac{d!}{n_0!\ n_1!\ \cdots\ n_9!}.$$

However, this also counts starting with the digit $0$.  Since this is not allowed, we need to subtract the number of permutations that start with a zero, which is counted similarly:
$$
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } n_0=0 \\
\binom{d-1}{n_0-1, n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_9} & \text{otherwise}. \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rebecca! But if I got it right, using the example at the start we would have
d = 5 (number of digits)
and since 2 is the only number that repeats itself
we would have 5!/2! = 60
now I don't think I understood the 0 subtraction, sorry if the matter sounds too trivial, if I get it we would have 4!/2! and subtracting 60 - 12 = 48, quite more than anticipated, what I'm missing of your explanation?

Comment: 2102 has d=4 digits, so that gives 4!/2!=12 (counting 0122, 0212, 0221, 1022, 1202, 1220, 2012, 2021, 2102, 2120, 2201, 2210) from which we correct by subtracting 3!/2!=3 (counting 0122, 0212, 0221), which results in 9 in total.

Comment: Oh so sorry, I posted an example with 4 digits and I've been trying this the whole day with a 5-digit example, so I did all wrong ! silly me. Thanks for your patience ! I can't upvote you right now so I will check this as answer and thank you once again